# Positioning elements on a HiDPi/Retina screen

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, retina-display

I have a responsive column set on the middle of the page with three buttons on it. Here is styling rule for column.

```
element.style {
padding: 30px 162px 20px;
margin-left: -162px;
visibility: visible;
background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246);
}
```

[image]
Now on testing it on a HiDPi screen the position of the buttons get distorted.
[image]

Can someone point me to any tutorial or any hint towards correcting this.

update:see this link rahul.pianissimo-band.com/hochzeit, and simulate it in both HiDPI and MDPI

Comment: Have you tried adding the viewport meta tag?  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">, I don't want to submit this as an answer as its hard to tell exactly what the problem is. You can read up on it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: @KevinF see this link http://rahul.pianissimo-band.com/hochzeit/, and simulate it in both HiDPI and MDPI